# What is a better way to pack 4 ints into ulong?

Tags: c#, int, ulong

I need to pack several int values(each value only ranging from 0 to 999) into ulong. I have a working method like below but can it be optimized?

I know it hurts your eyes with lots of 0's, sorry.

```
public class Test  {

    public void Start() {
        ulong testValue = 444333222111;

        Debug.Log(GetValue1(testValue) + " " + GetValue2(testValue) + " " + GetValue3(testValue) + " " + GetValue4(testValue)); // = 111 222 333 444

        SetValue1(ref testValue, 55);
        SetValue2(ref testValue, 9);
        SetValue3(ref testValue, 111);
        SetValue4(ref testValue, 999);

        Debug.Log(testValue); // = 999111009055
        Debug.Log(GetValue1(testValue) + " " + GetValue2(testValue) + " " + GetValue3(testValue) + " " + GetValue4(testValue)); // = 55 9 111 999
    }

    public int GetValue1(ulong i) => (int)(i % 1000);
    public void SetValue1(ref ulong i, int value) => i = i / 1000 * 1000 + (ulong)value;

    public int GetValue2(ulong i) => (int)(i % 1000000 / 1000);
    public void SetValue2(ref ulong i, int value) => i = i / 1000000 * 1000000 + (ulong)value * 1000 + i % 1000;

    public int GetValue3(ulong i) => (int)(i % 1000000000 / 1000000);
    public void SetValue3(ref ulong i, int value) => i = i / 1000000000 * 1000000000 + (ulong)value * 1000000 + i % 1000000;

    public int GetValue4(ulong i) => (int)(i % 1000000000000 / 1000000000);
    public void SetValue4(ref ulong i, int value) => i = i / 1000000000000 * 1000000000000 + (ulong)value * 1000000000 + i % 1000000000;

}
```

Comment: why in the world would you want to do this, out of curiosity?

Comment: 0-999 will fit into 10 bits (which runs 0-1023).  Shifting 10 times will be more efficient than your divides and modulus operations.  Perhaps even better, a ulong is 64 bits.  A short is 16 bits.  Create a struct using `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` that contains both a ulong and 4 shorts (nicely/explicitly layed out) and you can get very clear code, and an easy to read value

Comment: I believe you should try to solve your task using bitwise and shift c# operators. That's exactly what they are intended for. See here for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Comment: Ah, those ideas seem very nice. I will try them now. Thanks!

Comment: But do you need the whole ulong in the form of _999111009055_ ? Isn't it better to have a class that stores these 4 numbers and you get the different component numbers when you need them?

Comment: Yes, I guess using class would be better than packing and struct even better in my case. I'm glad I asked before resorting to packing. Thanks for the answer and comments.

Comment: If you don't need the ulong, you can use a `StructLayoutKind.Sequential` struct.  It will still be a 64 bit value type. There are advantages to using a value type for something like this (which may hold for you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.  First create a `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` struct like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct FourWords
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public ulong Whole;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort First;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public ushort Second;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public ushort Third;
    [FieldOffset(6)] public ushort Fourth;
}
```

Then you can access each of the First, Second,... fields like you expect:

```
 FourWords test = new FourWords();
 test.Second = 0x101;
 test.Fourth = 0xA0A;
 var xyz = test.Whole;
```

If you look at xyz in a debugger (in hex view), you see:

```
    xyz, h  0x0a0a000001010000  ulong
```

and you can see the 101 and the A0A.